# How to fully clear WebRTC connection?

Tags: javascript, streaming, webrtc, audio-streaming

I'm making a WebRTC app with multiple connections. I've been having trouble with deleting the connections from chrome://webrtc-internals/ using the .close() method alone, so I looked on StackOverflow for a similar problem and saw someone recommend setting the connections to null as well. I did that, but I still saw the connections in chrome://webrtc-internals/. How can I fully delete these connections?

```js
yourConn.close();
yourConn2.close();
yourConn3.close();
    
yourConn = null;
yourConn2 = null;
yourConn3 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

When we do `peerConn.close()` the running ICE proccesing and active stream are finalized. But you must make sure to remove all RTCPeerConnection references `peerConn = null`

Comment: There nothing more I can do? I did the close method on the connections and removed all references to them, but the connections aren't deleted chrome://webrtc-internals/. They are marked as closed, but I'm just worried that these closed connections will accumulate and lead to poor server performance. Any way to fix this?